# How to get Oracle variables into Amchart in JSP

Tags: jsp, oracle11g, amcharts

I have a very basic JSP code. It returns 3 variables from Oracle Database

```
    String program_name = "";
        Integer projects = 0;
        Integer operations = 0;

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        if(deger.equals("All Priorities"))
        {
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT PROGRAM_NAME prog_name, (SELECT COUNT(PRJ_TYPE) FROM EAD_PRJ_CURR_LIST LST WHERE LST.PROGRAM_ID= PG.PGM_PROGRAM_ID AND LST.PRJ_TYPE = 'Project') Project,(SELECT COUNT(PRJ_TYPE) FROM EAD_PRJ_CURR_LIST LST WHERE LST.PROGRAM_ID= PG.PGM_PROGRAM_ID AND LST.PRJ_TYPE = 'Operation') Operation FROM KCRT_FG_PFM_PROGRAM PG");
        }
        else
        {
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT PROGRAM_NAME prog_name, (SELECT COUNT(PRJ_TYPE) FROM EAD_PRJ_CURR_LIST LST WHERE LST.PROGRAM_ID= PG.PGM_PROGRAM_ID AND LST.PRJ_TYPE = 'Project') AS Project,(SELECT COUNT(PRJ_TYPE) FROM EAD_PRJ_CURR_LIST LST WHERE LST.PROGRAM_ID= PG.PGM_PROGRAM_ID AND LST.PRJ_TYPE = 'Operation') as Operation FROM KCRT_FG_PFM_PROGRAM PG");
        }
        while(rs.next())



          program_name = rs.getString("prog_name");
          projects = rs.getInt("Project");
          operations = rs.getInt("Operation");
```

This is the code for the chart, it is a bar chart -

```
    <!-- Chart code -->
                <script>
                var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
                    "type": "serial",
                     "theme": "light",
                    "categoryField": "List_Of_Programs",
                    "rotate": true,
                    "startDuration": 1,
                    "categoryAxis": {
                        "gridPosition": "start",
                        "position": "left"
                    },
                    "trendLines": [],
                    "graphs": [
                        {
                            "balloonText": "Projects:[[value]]",
                            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                            "id": "AmGraph-1",
                            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                            "title": "Projects",
                            "type": "column",
                            "valueField": "Projects"
                        },
                        {
                            "balloonText": "Operations:[[value]]",
                            "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                            "id": "AmGraph-2",
                            "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                            "title": "Operations",
                            "type": "column",
                            "valueField": "Operations"
                        }
                    ],
                    "guides": [],
                    "valueAxes": [
                        {
                            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                            "position": "top",
                            "axisAlpha": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "allLabels": [],
                    "balloon": {},
                    "titles": [],
                    "dataProvider": [
                        {
                            "List_Of_Programs": <%=projects%>,
                            "Projects": <%=projects%>,
                            "Operations": <%=operations%>
                        }],
                    "export": {
                        "enabled": true
                     }

                });
                </script>


                  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

I have both this encapsulated in a JSP file. The code is compiling fine, without any issues. However, I need help with the logic of printing the data from the earlier query (which has around 20 rows) into the chart.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

The dataProvider needs to be an array of object**s** (note, plural). What you're doing appears to be setting individual arrays(?) into each property into a single object in the dataProvider array. The dataProvider object should resemble something like this (using random data as an example):

```
"dataProvider": [{
  "List_Of_Programs": "Program A",
  "Projects": 13,
  "Operations": 10
}, {
  "List_Of_Programs": "Program B",
  "Projects": 25,
  "Operations": 28
}. 
// continue for each array element
]
```

(Note that this format is used in every demo on AmCharts' website.)

I'm not an expert on JSP or on best practices (although [this popped up in my brief foray into JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files), which is probably something you should look into), but you can use a JSON library like org.json to put all of your values into an array of objects and then serialize the array into a string similar to the above example. For instance, using your code above:

```
//assumes you're using the org.json library
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
while(rs.next()) {
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  obj.put("List_Of_Programs", rs.getString("prog_name"));
  obj.put("Projects", rs.getInt("Project"));
  obj.put("Operations", rs.getInt("Operation"));
  jsonArray.put(obj);
}
```

Once you have your array, print it out in your makeChart call in the dataProvider section:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
   // other properties omitted
  "dataProvider": <%=jsonArray%> //will serialize as the array from above
});
```